# How to add data in list below?

Tags: python

i have a list :

```
List = [[['1','2'],['2','4']],[['1','4'],['4','8']],[['53','8'],['8','2'],['2','82']]]
```

That i want add reverse data to list

To be:

```
[[['1','2'],['2','4'],['2','1'],['4','2']],[['1','4'],['4','8'],['4','1'],['8','4']],[['53','8'],['8','2'],['2','82'],['8','53'],['2','8'],['82','2']]]
```

Comment: Hi Joy, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych No, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the list and extend it with the reversed elements:

```
List = [[['1','2'],['2','4']],[['1','4'],['4','8']],[['53','8'],['8','2'],['2','82']]]

for sublist in List:
    sublist.extend([pair[::-1] for pair in sublist])
```

In the end, `List` will be:

```
[[['1', '2'], ['2', '4'], ['2', '1'], ['4', '2']],
 [['1', '4'], ['4', '8'], ['4', '1'], ['8', '4']],
 [['53', '8'], ['8', '2'], ['2', '82'], ['8', '53'], ['2', '8'], ['82', '2']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested list comprehension that iterates over the sub-lists and reverses sub-lists within, before merging them with the original sub-lists:

```
[l + [s[::-1] for s in l] for l in List]
```

Comment: Would be helpful for the OP if you explain the one liner. At least add some explanation  to your answer. It always helps

Answer (score 0):

While this answer may not be the most Pythonic of answers given the original intent of the function I use was for reverse iteration over sequences. This accomplishes your goal in a concise, readable fashion, imho.

I have made use of the function `reversed()`. This function will return a reverse-order `list_reverseiterator` object based on your original list. Considering this returned object is not a list, we can use the `list` type change function as such: `list(reversed(List))` and this will provide you with the reversed original list. Then, the original candidate `List` is appended with the newly reversed list to create the desired output you had requested.

[Source 1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0322/)
[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)

```
List = [[['1','2'],['2','4']],[['1','4'],['4','8']],[['53','8'],['8','2'],['2','82']]]
print("Here is the original list: ", List)
ListReverse = list(reversed(List))
List.append(ListReverse)
print("Here is your final list: ", List)
```

While the print statements are accessory to the original ask, I have included them so you have a verification of the working solution.